# Error 'No suitable method found to override' in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, unity3d-mirror

I'm following a tutorial video for setting up a lobby for players to host and join a game and I've been getting these errors:

```
error CS0115: 'NetworkManagerLobby.OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection)': no suitable method found to override

error CS0115: 'NetworkManagerLobby.OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection)': no suitable method found to override
```

```
    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)

    public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
```

I have included `using Mirror`, and the class inherits from Network Manager.

Unity version 2021.3.5f1

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: If you hover the `NetworkManager` and press F12 (assuming you are using a reasonable IDE like Visual Studio / Rider etc) does it actually bring you to the correct type?

Comment: @derHugo I'm after doing that and it said 'No definition found for NetworkManager'

Comment: Have you installed Mirror?

Comment: @BugFinder yes I downloaded it from the Unity asset store and imported it into my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your agument types are correct? I suppose it should be of type "NetworkConnectionToClient"

```
public virtual void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)

public virtual void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnectionToClient conn) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! that's gotten rid of the errors