# 'No suitable method found to override' in Unity 2022.3.14F1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overriding

I was watching the Steam online tutorial for Unity on YouTube and I came across this error in Unity:

> 'CustomNetworkManager.OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection)': no suitable method found to override
>
> wrong line in code ; public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection conn)

I am using unity 2022.3 14f1 version, mirror is in the latest version. I tried the following code to solve the error but the error was still there:

```
public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
```

and

```
public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnectionToClient conn) {}
```

All the code:

```
public class CustomNetworkManager : NetworkManager
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerObjectController GamePlayerPrefab;
    public List<PlayerObjectController> GamePlayers { get; } = new List<PlayerObjectController>();

    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn) // Perhaps the Wrong part is here?
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Lobby")
        {
            PlayerObjectController GamePLayerInstance = Instantiate(GamePlayerPrefab);
            GamePLayerInstance.ConnectionID = conn.connectionId;
            GamePLayerInstance.PlayerIdNumer = GamePlayers.Count + 1;
            GamePLayerInstance.PlayerSteamID = (ulong)SteamMatchmaking.GetLobbyMemberByIndex((CSteamID)SteamLobby.Instance.CurrentLobbyID, GamePlayers.Count);

            NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, GamePLayerInstance.gameObject);
            GamePlayers.Add(GamePLayerInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the video and timestamp, please?

Comment: What Unity version is the tutorial for? And what is the used multiuser solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your tutorial refers to an older version of Unity.

This seems to refer to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.OnServerAddPlayer.html) from good old UNet => [UNet deprecation plan](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unet-deprecation-and-removal-plan-2021-update-and-faq.1137190/) spoiler: it was deprecated and most of it removed in recent versions.

See e.g. [NetworkManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetManager.html)

> Important: UNet is a deprecated solution, and a new Multiplayer and Networking
> Solution (Netcode for GameObjects) is under development. For more information and next steps see the information on the Unity Netcode for GameObjects website.

Also see [Migrating from UNet to NetCode for GameObjects](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/installation/upgrade_from_UNet)

Note that this one also has a [NetworkManager](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/components/networkmanager) which is probably the main cause for this naming confusion

I think in your case you could probably add a callback to [`NetworkManager.OnClientConnectedCallback`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.7/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.OnClientConnectedCallback.html)

> ```
> NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += OnClientConnectedCallback;
> ```

> The callback to invoke once a client connects. This callback is only ran on the server and on the local client that connects.

(See also [Connection Notification Manager example](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/components/networkmanager/#connection-notification-manager-example))

You still have to handle the spawning differently though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the method exactly with this signaature:

```
public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

All the code:

```
public class CustomNetworkManager : NetworkManager
{
    [SerializeField] private PlayerObjectController GamePlayerPrefab;
    public List<PlayerObjectController> GamePlayers { get; } = new List<PlayerObjectController>();

    public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        // Your code here
    }

    public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn) // Perhaps the Wrong part is here?
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Lobby")
        {
            PlayerObjectController GamePLayerInstance = Instantiate(GamePlayerPrefab);
            GamePLayerInstance.ConnectionID = conn.connectionId;
            GamePLayerInstance.PlayerIdNumer = GamePlayers.Count + 1;
            GamePLayerInstance.PlayerSteamID = (ulong)SteamMatchmaking.GetLobbyMemberByIndex((CSteamID)SteamLobby.Instance.CurrentLobbyID, GamePlayers.Count);

            NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, GamePLayerInstance.gameObject);
            GamePlayers.Add(GamePLayerInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP states they already tried that .. it would however in no way address the fact that `OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnection conn)` has apparently no implementation in the base class that you could override ...

Comment: Glad you found something. Feel free to post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Both OnServerConnect and OnServerAddPlayer should have argument of type NetworkConnectionToClient

```
public override void OnServerAddPlayer(NetworkConnectionToClient conn)
```

[Error 'No suitable method found to override' in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928238/error-no-suitable-method-found-to-override-in-unity/72930173#72930173)